# Inverting how an object is coupled to other object's events

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I currently have an object, volumeSlider, which is affected by two other controls' events:

```
var volumeSlider = $('#VolumeSlider');

$('#MuteButton').on('mouseenter', function() {
    volumeSlider.fadeIn('fast');
}

$('#Controls').on('mouseleave', function() {
    volumeSlider.fadeOut('fast');
}
```

I would like to invert this such that volumeSlider 'listens' for the events on MuteButton and Controls instead of being told to respond to them. Is this possible? Something like:

```
//Pseudo-Code:
volumeSlider.on('#MuteButton.mouseenter'){
    this.fadeIn('fast');
}.on('#Controls.mouseleave'){
    this.fadeOut('fast');
}
```

Is jQuery's http://api.jquery.com/bind/ useful here?

Comment: What you are doing currently is not possible, but You can fire custom events from `MuteButton's and Control's` events and listen for them on `volumeSlider`

Comment: I'm not really sure why you'd want to do this. Do you want to be able to refer to `volumeSlider` through `this` inside your event handler? Then use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) on your event handler function to bind it to the `volumeSlider` context. Do you want to group all these elements into one media player control? Then you should consider wrapping everything inside a jQuery plugin which manages these elements, binds handlers and exposes methods such as `play()` or `mute()` which also update the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one suggestion:

```
volumeSlider.on('dosomething', function(e) {
    $(this).fadeIn('fast');
});

$('#MuteButton').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    volumeSlider.trigger('dosomething');
}
```